# MySQL Selecting Status from Database Issue

Tags: java, mysql

Ok, so I am a little new to MySQL querys and I am wondering if this would be the correct syntax to get if a value is false in a row.

```
"SELECT `status` 
 FROM `friends` 
 WHERE `requester`= '"+requester+"' 
 AND `requested` = '"+requested+"' 
 AND `status`= 'false'";
```

If that is wrong, I'm trying to fetch the requests where you are the requester and the status is false through a java method.

Comment: why would you select the status if you specify that it is false in the WHERE? and did you mean NULL?

Comment: what is your `datatype` for column `status` ?

Comment: I am trying to check if the status is true or false. As I said, I am a little new to this kind of MySQL querying.

Comment: @Pravin it is a varchar

Comment: Your query want work only if there is some white space char in your value else your query is fine to check try this use like **"SELECT `status` FROM `friends` WHERE `requester`= '"+requester+"' AND `requested` = '"+requested+"' AND `status` like '%false%'";**

Comment: @Pravin I'm going to try yours out and see how it works.

Comment: @RDNachoz I would recommend adding in some sample data and expected results if you are still having trouble with this, it would help others to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: in regards to what @McAdam331 was saying please read [**My Post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) it has a lot of tips that can help you when asking a question to get a good answer

Comment: @RDNachoz did my answer help? do you still have an issue?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I got it to work with Pravin's code. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

first thing i would do is check to be sure the variables contain what you want them to. maybe even put in the data directly to the query at first without variables. get it to what you want it to be.

```
System.out.println("the requester is: ");
System.out.println(requester);
System.out.println("the requested is: ");
System.out.println(requested);

"SELECT 0 FROM friends WHERE requester= '"+requester+"' AND requested = '"+requested+"' AND status= 'false'"
```

generally 0 is false and 1 is true in programming languages so you can just pull out a 0 when its false.

you may want to also do a like comparison on the requester and requested. you could do it on the status column if you want but that shouldn't be necessary

```
"SELECT 0 FROM friends WHERE requester LIKE '%"+requester+"%' AND requested LIKE '%"+requested+"%' AND status= 'false'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query want work only if there is some white space char in your value else your query is fine to check try this use like

```
 SELECT status FROM friends WHERE requester= '"+requester+"' AND requested = '"+requested+"' AND status like '%false';
```

Answer (score -2):

try this man

```
status is false
```

in your case, false is a string, not a boolean

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?